# Creating a List<T>, issues with formatting

Tags: c#, list

I'm getting all sorts of compile errors from the code below.  I'm not quite sure how to Add items to a List when I have a List setups as shown below. I wan't to basically maintain the values set within the StockEntry class, and use the class StockItem as a Count.  Using... _stocks.Value.Count++

```
public class StockEntry
{
  public string Name;
  public PeriodType Period;
  public int Min;


  public StockEntry(string Name, PeriodType Period, int Min)
  {
    this.Name = Name;
    this.Period = Period;
    this.Min = Min;
  }
}

public class StockItem<T>
{
  public T Value;

  public StockItem() {} 
  public StockItem(T val) {Value = val;}    
}

 List<StockItem<StockEntry>> _stocks = new List<StockItem<StockEntry>>();

 protected override void Initialize()
 {                                  
  _stocks.Add(new StockItem(StockEntry("ABC", PeriodType.Minute, 5)));          
  _stocks.Add(new StockItem(StockEntry("ACE", PeriodType.Minute, 5)));
  _stocks.Add(new StockItem(StockEntry("ACN", PeriodType.Minute, 5)));
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the tag. This is one of that cases where Java is undifferentiable from C# :) (Besides of one clue: `string` instead of `String`)

Comment: there seems to be at least one missing or misplaced curly brace here. What is _stocks a member of?

Comment: In what way are these "issues with formatting"?

Comment: @user2850280, check my answer, apply it to all of related usages, and if it works you can accept my answer by toggling a left side mark to green.

Answer (score 3):

Aside from anything else, this could be the problem:

```
_stocks.Add(new StockItem(StockEntry("ABC", PeriodType.Minute, 5)));
```

(and the similar lines).

`StockItem` is a generic class, so you need to specify the type argument:

```
_stocks.Add(new StockItem<StockEntry>(StockEntry("ABC", PeriodType.Minute, 5)));
```

If you want to avoid that somewhat redundant specification, you could create a static generic method in a *non-generic* type:

```
// Overload StockItem<T> by generic arity
public static class StockItem
{
    public static StockItem<T> Of(T item)
    {
        return new StockItem<T>(item);
    }
}
```

Then:

```
_stocks.Add(StockItem.Of(StockEntry("ABC", PeriodType.Minute, 5)));
```

That said, it's not really clear why `StockItem` needs to be generic in the first place. And I'd definitely avoid using a public field - at least make it an automatically implemented property. (Ideally IMO, make it a readonly property backed by a readonly field set in the constructor, and remove the parameterless constructor. But then I'm a fan of immutability.) Likewise I'd get rid of the public fields in `StockEntry`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be, `_stocks.Add(new StockItem<StockEntry>(new StockEntry("ABC", PeriodType.Minute, 5)));`?

Comment: As I wrote in my  answer seems to be just because of lack of *new* keyword. IMHO compiler implicitly can determine the type (This days I'm far from programming and this is just my guess).

Comment: Jon & Rohan thanks that fixed it. I'm definately a beginner to programming, someone else was helping me with this but cant seem to reach them.  The class StockItem<T> what exactly is this doing or where can I possibly read about this on MSDN? I'm not understanding why the individual was creating that extra class to encapsulate the first class of StockEntry?  Or what StockItem() {} exactly is doing and what the T is.

Answer (score 2):

I think if you add `new` keyword to this line:

```
_stocks.Add(new StockItem(StockEntry("ABC", PeriodType.Minute, 5)));
```

your problem will be resolve.

```
_stocks.Add(new StockItem(new StockEntry("ABC", PeriodType.Minute, 5)));
```

Answer (score 0):

_stocks and Initialize need to be part of a class - they are not currently.

Presumably you want them as part of StockItem:

```
public class StockItem<T>
{
  public T Value;

public StockItem() {} 
public StockItem(T val) {Value = val;}  
} // The class StockItem ends with this bracket
```